# The line code connection.connect(); not wokring on java android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, connect

i want to download a picture from a website .
I tried the code from here : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.
When debeuging : the third line works and i have a confirmation message, but the problem is that the fourth line code : " connection.connect()" never works and i don't have the confirmation message after it , and no error message also .. I don't know why .

Thank's for any help

```
URL url = new URL(src);                     
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: Does not work in which way ?

Comment: the code stop there , and i have no message error

Comment: Stops where ? There are many lines of code

Comment: connection.connect(); don't work

Comment: 1) Are you behind a firewall? 2) Are you sure that the server you are connecting to is available and the port you are using is open? How have you checked it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very precise. Is there an exception or stacktrace ?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Yes i'm using the application on my phone and debuging it . and i tried many pictures that i can acces directly from any navigator .. and in all the tentatives : connection.connect(); didn't work

Comment: my code is surounded by try and catch and i have no error message or exception that i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it was because of StrictMode AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork on verbose log cat . and the solution was by adding the 2 lines of code after the oncreate :
    `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`